# Ошибка в RedBeanPHP при использование 2 баз данных

Tags: php, mysql, php7, redbeanphp, php8

Почему при использование 2 баз данных одновременно вылезает такая ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught RedBeanPHP\RedException: Unsupported database
> (). in C:\xampp\htdocs\Вёрстка\Йога\libs\rb-mysql.php:12235 Stack
> trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Вёрстка\Йога\libs\rb-mysql.php(12176):
> RedBeanPHP\Facade::createToolbox('root', '', NULL, false, false,
> Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Вёрстка\Йога\db3.php(5):
> RedBeanPHP\Facade::addDatabase('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Вёрстка\Йога\admin\scripts\add_post.php(21):
> require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Вёрстка\Йога\libs\rb-mysql.php on line 12235

Код подключения к первой БД:

```
<?php
require "libs/rb-mysql.php";

// Подключаемся к БД

R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=admins', 'root', ' ' );

// Проверка подключения к БД

if(!R::testConnection()) die('No DB connection!');

session_start(); // Создаем сессию для авторизации

?>
```

Код подключения к 2 БД:

```
https://github.com/1yaroslav/class.forms.php/blob/main/db2.php
```

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Я уже пытался писать addDatabase и selectDatabase - не работает

Comment: "не работает" понятие растяжимое. Появляется ошибка? Данные выбираются из первой базы, хотя выбрана вторая?

Comment: @ArchDemon Fatal error: Uncaught RedBeanPHP\RedException: Unsupported database (). in C:\xampp\htdocs\Вёрстка\Йога\libs\rb-mysql.php:12235 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Вёрстка\Йога\libs\rb-mysql.php(12176): RedBeanPHP\Facade::createToolbox('root', '', NULL, false, false, Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Вёрстка\Йога\db3.php(5): RedBeanPHP\Facade::addDatabase('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Вёрстка\Йога\admin\scripts\add_post.php(21): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Вёрстка\Йога\libs\rb-mysql.php on line 12235

Comment: На этой строчке require("../../db2.php");
require("../../db3.php");